# Error when deploying applications to cloud foundry using cloud bees plugin

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudbees

I have integrated my Cloud Foundry account with Cloud Bees as mentioned in the url -
http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/dotcom/integration/cloudbees/
and trying to deploy few sample applications from github.

Build was successful every time but when I went for app-deployment using this plugin, it gave one exception (one particular exception for 2-3 applications I have tried).

```
[INFO] Deployment done in 1.2 sec
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying as (jenkins) to the svcnvghi293 account
[cloudbees-deployer] Deploying null
com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.exceptions.DeployException: Could not create DeployEvent
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl.createEvent(RunEngineImpl.java:132)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl.createEvent(RunEngineImpl.java:51)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.perform(Engine.java:82)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:95)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:728)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:703)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:994)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:650)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1530)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:477)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl$EventImpl.<init>(RunEngineImpl.java:208)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.run.RunEngineImpl.createEvent(RunEngineImpl.java:124)
    ... 12 more
Build step 'Deploy applications' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

does anyone have any idea about this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging I figured out which account you have.

The issue is that you had left the CloudBees RUN@Cloud host service in the list of host services to deploy to but you had not provided a complete configuration for it, e.g. see the "Application Id cannot be empty" red error text in this screenshot

[image: Screenshot from your instance (taken using CloudBees Support super-powers)]

I have removed this host section and saved your `hellospring` job. Build 8 shows a successful deployment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and appropriate solution. I was concentrating on cloudfoundry section and completely overlooked red error text for CloudBees RUN@Cloud.

Comment: Just have one more question, the doc http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/dotcom/integration/cloudbees/ shows the process of integrating it with public cloud.  But, we need to integrate CloudBees with our private cloud domain. Can we do that ?

Comment: The API end point should allow such configuration though there are some additional tweaks required to get that working. Also, there are changes coming down the line for Cloud Foundry version 2. The version 1 public service will be EOL on June 30th 2013. The java API for deploying to CFv2 has not been written yet, though we are promised it soon, so some things feel slightly up in the air to me right now. If you have more detailed questions I think you should contact sales@cloudbees as that way we could have a more private discussion.